# Win 8.1 auto sign out after login

Tags: windows-8.1, login-screen, logout, sign-out

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro update 1

I have 2 accounts: L(always used, admin user)  and F (Standard account)
After a long time not logged in with user F, now I cannot log in with F account, the system automatic log out immediately after login. I don't know why, I have antivirus, not install strange software and my favorite account (L) is working 100%
Now when I create any extra account, it cannot be logged in too

I am googling a lots, and there are many result said: it's a Win 8 error and not solution fount yet
Please help

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:
Reboot windows in "Safe mode", login to the "locked" account, and, OMG, do nothing, just restart again in normal mode, and you can login to it smoothly!